# How to create RavenDB index for linked documents

Tags: ravendb

I have the following design: Debtors are managed by Agents. Each are stored as independent documents, with id-based references to one-another.  Each communication between an Agent and his debtors is recorded as 3rd independent document, with an id-based reference to the debtor.  It is thus easy to create an index CommunicationsByDebtor, as follows:

```
from c in docs.Communications
select new { c.DebtorId }
```

However, how do I get define the map for an index CommunicationsByAgent?
I've tried this, but it don't compile:

```
from c in docs.Communications
from d in docs.Debtors
where d.Id == c.Communication_Debtor
select new { d.AgentId }
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from c in docs.Communications
let d = LoadDocument<Debtor>(c.Communication_Debtor)
select new { d.AgentId }
```

Reference: [Indexing Related Documents](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes/indexing-related-documents)

Comment: I get these two errors: 1) The non-generic method 'Raven.Database.Linq.AbstractViewGenerator.LoadDocument(string)' cannot be used with type arguments
2) The type or namespace name 'Debtors' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I suspect the 1st one will be resolved by me getting the right type definition for the 2nd one? I've tried Debtors, debtors, debtor, docs.Debtor, docs.Debtors...

Comment: ok got it...had to do this...from c in docs.Communications
let d = LoadDocument(string.Format("debtors/{0}",c.Communication_Debtor))
select new { d.AgentId }

Comment: seems you can't specify a Type for LoadDocument;  and it expects the variable to be a string of the format [collectionname]/id

Comment: so I'll accept your answer for leading me down the right track, but you may want to edit it accordingly. Thanks Matt.

Comment: You must be using integer or guid ids.  Things that execute on the server (like LoadDocument) will always need string identifiers.  Your solution should work fine.